# maven > mixed scala/Java project > scala: error: value toScan is not a member of object org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am following the link: http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html
to try to compile a mixed Scala/Java project with mvn command - mvn compile - but got some error:
scala: error: value toScan is not a member of object org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil is a class in the hbase dependency jar, and I indeed included that dependency jar and I am sure that the method toScan() is from the class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.

So what is the reason for this problem?

Comment: can you show the call?

Comment: My command is: mvn compile

Comment: the call to `toScan` I meant

Comment: /HBaseHelper.scala:28: error: value toScan is not a member of object org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil
[ERROR]     val proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan)

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to Scala library incompatibility try adding something like:
    
        1.8
        2.10.6

to your pom.xml file